# @Service @Controller java spring

Tags: java, spring

Пишу программу и хочу использовать аннотацию `@Service`. Я всегда писал логическую часть в классе, в котором есть аннотация `@Controller`. Мне сказали, что нужно писать всю логику в классе, в котором есть аннотация `@Service`, и отсюда нужно присылать данные в контроллер и оттуда - в `jsp` либо `html`.

Не знаю, это правильно вообще или нет. Где-то читал, что аннотацию `@Service` ставят для бизнес-логики. Написал программу точно так же, но логическая часть уже в том классе, в котором была аннотация `@Service`.

И сразу возникла проблема: не могу сделать `return"redirect:/` в контроллере. Я никогда не делал это. Может быть, допустил ошибки или этот `@Service` вообще нужна для другого решения?

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отправить данные в контроллер.

> @service

```
@Service
public class MainService {
      
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String str(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
```

> @Controller

```
    @Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String mainController(ModelMap modelMap){
        modelMap.addAttribute("newUser",new User());
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Изменил вопрос спустя 3 года
Неплох

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам правильно сказали, всю бизнеслогику стоит писать в сервисах. В вашем случае, бизнес логика это вот эта строка:

```
map.addAttribute("user", new User());
```

Её можно вынести в сервис:

```
@Service
public class MainService {

    public void newUser(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("user", new User());
    }
}
```

А в контроллере вызывать её в соответствующем методе.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    MainService mainService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String str(ModelMap map) {
        mainService.newUser(map);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное